# undefined local variable or method when trying to iterate through array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, iteration

I'm trying to `iterate` through an `array` defined in a `model`, to show all the days from the array, but I get this error.

```
"undefined local variable or method `day'"
```

I'm a newbie and I can't figure out how to fix it, so any help would be much appreciated.

**schedule.rb**

```
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord

  def self.days
    ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
  end

end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<% Schedule.days.each |day| %>
<h2><%= day.titleize %>: <%= Date.today.send(day) %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `do`

```
<% Schedule.days.each do |day| %>
```

Just fix the syntax and it should work.